# What are the advatanges of less?

Tags: javascript, css, less

http://lesscss.org/

Yeah the language syntax looks cool, but are there any significant advantages?

Because from what I see there you actually write more CSS, and since the less stylesheet gets compiled by javascript you get a un-styled site for a few seconds...

Comment: If you want to use it, use it. If you don't, you don't use it. That's your decision. It might be useful in bigger projects because of macros. And nesting sounds interesting :). And if you really want, you can make LESS stylesheet and when you want to use it, just compile it to CSS.

Comment: It may appear you write more markup in LESS, but from personal experience LESS is far, far better than vanilla CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a precompiler (ruby's got a cool one, got it running under win).

Try writing a site in less and you'll never want to get back to normal css again :) my own experience...

Comment: can you share the reasons why you don't want to get back to css?

Comment: @Lessy It's more a case of try it yourself - that's the best way to find out. Also, there is a [LESS PHP compiler](http://leafo.net/lessphp/).

Comment: @Petr +1 for your second paragraph; I went through the same experience; LESS really is wonderful.

Comment: @Lessy Just check all the good stuff less has to offer. Probably the strongest reason for less is not having to write the parent elements over and over again.

Answer (score 5):

That is if you use lesscss for **client side** sheet generation.

You can also use lesscss on the **server side** or even **compile** your sheets before hand.

For example, if you are using **node.js** you can generate your sheets on the server. 
Additionally, if you want, you can use it as a way to write more manageable templates and then "compile" your sheets to generate a formed style sheet for when you are reading for production.

I think it makes perferct sense, because it means that while you are in **development**, you can change a collection of colors in a single hex color change. When you are ready to deploy, you can compile before hand and then distribute that style sheet with your project.

*Think about manageability* and using the command line compiler.

### Command Line

> http://lesscss.org/
>
> Less comes with a binary, which lets you invoke the compiler from the
>   command-line, as such:

```
$ lessc styles.less
```

This will output the compiled CSS to stdout, you may then redirect it to a file of your choice:

```
$ lessc styles.less > styles.css
```

To output minified CSS, simply pass the -x option.

Comment: +1 for variables (colors, also styles)! As I've said in another answer, there is a [LESS PHP compiler](http://leafo.net/lessphp/) which will only re-compile if the `.less` file has changed, making it both server-side and very resource-friendly.

Comment: Yep. Connected with Assetic, it would mean that you get all the powers of less with zero negative.

Answer (score 5):

Why would you write more CSS using LESS? In the contrary, you write less. And the code that you write is way more verbose than normal css. You can create groups better, use inheritance... You just have a way better overview over your styling than you do with CSS.

My CSS-file for a project currently has over 800 lines... in LESS, it's just around 150.

And to the javascript-compiling: I generally use an offline compiler and upload just the compiled CSS, so I don't have to fuss with the JS client.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a [LESS PHP compiler](http://leafo.net/lessphp/), which I use all the time. I think the best way to work out why it's better than CSS is to use it yourself, but I'll summarise some things:

- If you have theme colours used all over the place, for example, and want to change them, it's very easy with LESS's variable system.
- You actually write less markup than vanilla CSS, due to not having to retype long selector strings.
- If you want to, say, use cross-browser rounded corners, the mixins reduce repetition to almost nothing; all you do is create a class with style definitions in it, and then simply "mix it in". Essentially it's a re-usable function. If you need to change something specific to all rounded corners elements, you just change the single function.
- `Yeah the language syntax looks cool` Personally I think this is rather dismissive and ignorant; if you have a look around the LESS examples, you will see it is *miles* ahead of normal CSS in terms of usability and speed of development.

There are more reasons, but these should be enough to get you started.

Comment: is it compatible with css? I mean, what happens if I pass a normal CSS file trough that compiler?

Comment: It's already valid CSS, so nothing will change; it will end up in the compiled CSS file as-is.